How do I make an IK rig
I need to know how to make an IK rig. I've watched a bunch of tutorials and stuff, but, everything i try to do breaks the mesh. So if you can help me with this I'd appreciate it. I'd also really appreciate it if someone would rerig it I'd also appreciate that. Link here:

Thank you!

Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, we are a question and answer site aimed at providing users with localized assistance along the way, rather than solve the whole issue for them by presenting ready-made solutions. For commissioning work, job posts or hiring someone, there is a Jobs section over at Blender Artists Forum. Otherwise, could rephrase your post to read more like a direct inquiry showing efforts towards your goal, rather than ask for someone to do it for you, so it can be reopened?

In Edit mode you need to bend a bit the elbow backwards (1), create a pole target bone behind the elbow (2) that you parent to the root bone (so you'll need to create a root bone at the bottom of the armature that will be the master bone), this pole target will orientate the elbow, create a controller bone (3) that you parent to the root bone, parent the hand to the controller bone (4):

Give an IK constraint to the forearm, select the controller and pole target, set the Pole Angle so that the arm is correctly rotated, set the Chain Length:

Result:


I'm using the lower torso bone as the root bone. Will that work?

it's better to create a brand new bone, put it at the feet level, parent all the controller bones / pole target bones / lower torso bone to this root bone

Is it the same with the legs?

Yes exactly the same

How do i make an ik rig for the torso?

There's generally no ik for the torso

You can try though if you find it useful for your character

i need an ik for torso to make him sit

create a root bone, do the IK for the legs, and if you want to sit down the character, move down the first spine bone (Bone.003)
